# SML: Polymorphic function that calls another instantiation of itself

Tags: recursion, polymorphism, sml

Is there a way, to write a polymorphic function (in sml), that calls itself with arguments of different type than the arguments it has got?

For example, I was looking on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23838733/1055952), (it has the declaration `datatype ('a,'b)alterlist = Nil| element of 'a*('b,'a)alterlist;`) and intuitively, I would like to implement the function `unzip`, as:

```
fun unzip Nil = ([],[]) |
    unzip (element(x,l)) = let val (b,a)=unzip l in (x::a,b) end;
```

The type inference system understands it as `('a,'a) alterlist -> 'a list * 'a list`, but I want something of type `('a,'b) alterlist -> 'a list * 'b list` (such that the inner call is to a `('b,'a) alterlist -> 'b list * 'a list`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is [polymorphic recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_recursion), which is not implemented in standard ML.

This is however implemented in Haskell (and as @seanmcl pointed out, ocaml):

```hs
import Prelude hiding(unzip)

data Alterlist a b = Nil | Elem a (Alterlist b a)

unzip :: Alterlist a b -> ([a], [b])
unzip Nil = ([], [])
unzip (Elem x l) =
    let (b, a) = unzip l
    in (x : a, b)

x = Elem 1 (Elem True (Elem 5 (Elem False Nil)))

*Main> unzip x
([1,5],[True,False])
```

Comment: polymorphic recursion is supported by ocaml as well